# Ubuntu One Triplicated my contacts -- how can I delete all contacts so I can start over?

Tags: ubuntu-one, contacts, delete

I need to delete all contacts in Ubuntu One. Doing this one at a time is excruciating and horrible. How can I just get rid of all contacts?

Answer (score 2):

Did this happen with phone sync?  If it did, be careful as the instructions below may also delete the contacts in your phone when you re-sync.

The simplest way to delete everything is probably using our new bulk delete option.
To do this:

- Go to: https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/contacts/
- Click "Select all"
- Delete